# Calculation within function not iterating correctly (R)

Tags: r, loops, iteration, calculation

I am trying to write a function that calculates my salary increase every year if I assume the same percent increase each year.

I have tried some of the following code already, but it just outputs the first iteration of the calculation several times.

Here is my function:

```
salary_func=function(a,b){
  for(i in 1:a){
    c=b+(b*0.035)
    print(c)
  }
}

salary_func(5,100000)
```

The first argument should be the number of years I'd like to "forecast" out and the second argument should be the starting salary.  So, I'd like to see output that reads:

```
[1] 103500
[1] 107122.5
```

and so on until the a-th argument.

But it just reads:

```
[1] 103500
[1] 103500
```

What little piece am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either eliminate `c` altogether (just use `b`) or *initialize* `c`, and update `c` relative to its previous value, rather than the original value of `b`. The following works:

```
salary_func=function(a,b){
  c = b
  for(i in 1:a){
    c=c+(c*0.035)
    print(c)
  }
}
```

For example:

```
> salary_func(5,100000)
[1] 103500
[1] 107122.5
[1] 110871.8
[1] 114752.3
[1] 118768.6
```

Having said that, not that a function which *prints* rather than returns a value is not very useful.

Answer (score 3):

The return value of the computation must be assigned back to `b`, in order for it to change. Otherwise the `for` loop computes the same value `a` times.

```
salary_func <- function(a, b){
  for(i in seq_len(a)){
    b <- b + (b*0.035)
    print(b)
  }
}

salary_func(5, 100000)
#[1] 103500
#[1] 107122.5
#[1] 110871.8
#[1] 114752.3
#[1] 118768.6
```

Another solution is to take advantage of R's vectorized operations and of the fact that the function computes a compound growth.

Version 2 doesn't print the values. it returns them.

```
salary_func2 <- function(a, b){
    b*(1 + 0.035)^seq_len(a)
}

salary_func2(5, 100000)
#[1] 103500.0 107122.5 110871.8 114752.3 118768.6
```

Comment: Simply getting rid of `c` is probably the best approach.